# Developing App To Stream Media to UPnP devices :Android

Tags: android, upnp

I am making an application which Streams media from the Internet,it can be from any source like Youtube,or any url. I am able to stream media from my android device.

Now i want to extend it to be streamed to UPnP devices in my network.

Any help on how i can find the list of UPnP devices in my network, then share media with that devices..

I found the little help from 
http://teleal.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html

They have their own API for using UPnP service.

Any body who have worked on UPnP service can help me.

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HI, i have the same idea, how far are you with the app?
There is a java lib you can use to connect and search upnp devices.
http://www.sbbi.net/site/upnp/index.html
Hope it helps.